# Need Help in Jenkins-Job DSL promotion

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

Iam working on creating a Build promotion using Jenkins-JOb DSL-Paramterized build.

My Scripts looks as,

```
Job('sampleMavenProj') {
  triggers { scm("*/5 * * * *") }
  scm { git('file:///work/SampleTest')   }

rootPOM("pom.xml")
goals('clean')
wrappers {
    preBuildCleanup()
    release {
        preBuildSteps {
            maven {                 
                rootPOM('pom.xml')
                goals("build-helper:parse-version")
                goals("versions:set")

            }
        }
        postSuccessfulBuildSteps {
            maven {
                rootPOM('pom.xml')
                goals("package")
            }


        }
    }
}

}

promotions("") {
  promotion("Development") {
    icon("star-red")
    conditions {
        manual('')
    }
    actions {
        shell('echo This is a DownStream Job;')
        }  
}
```

But when i build the JOb , it fails saying ,

Processing provided DSL script
ERROR: (script, line 31) No signature of method: script.promotions() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, script$_run_closure2) values: [, script$_run_closure2@4fcac57f]
Finished: FAILURE

Which is at , promotions area. Please let me on this.
Thanks for all the responses.

Comment: Seems like the Prompted build plugin that i am using is not working. I have to use the 2.26 version from"https://github.com/Russell-IO/promoted-builds-plugin/releases" to use the code. This solved my issues. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the Prompted build plugin that i am using is not working. I have to use the 2.26 version from"https://github.com/Russell-IO/promoted-builds-plugin/releases" to use the code. This solved my issues. thanks